# direction of poles of 2 cascading systems

Tags: matrices, control-theory, linear-control

> Given the following system: $$G(s)=G_2(s)G_1(s)=\begin{bmatrix}
> > \begin{array}{c|c}   A_2&B_2\\ \hline   C_2&D_2 \end{array}
> > \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \begin{array}{c|c}   A_1&B_1\\ \hline  
> > C_1&D_1 \end{array} \end{bmatrix}$$ I need to show that
> $pdir_o(G,p_i)=G_2(p_i)pdir_o(G_1,p_i)$ knowing that $p_i\in
> > spec(A_1)$ for all $p_i\notin spec(A_2)$
>
> (We can not assume invertibility or minimality of $G_i$)

My way of approaching this problem is a such: we know that we can't assume invertibility or minimality of the system, but i do know that
$$pdir_o(G,p_i)=Cker(p_iI-A)$$
which helps me with $pdir_o(G_1,p_i)$ but im still stuck with the $G_2(p_i)$ part

help will be appreciated